# React : How to create app after forgetting to quit last session (npx create-react-app my-react-app)

Tags: create-react-app, npx

What shall I do if I forgot to quit the last session and have to start a new react app

Answer (score -1):

First delete the whole react app folder and start from new .
Step 1 : Create a folder named **React** .
Step 2 : Then open the React folder and run **npm cache clean --force** in a new terminal .
Step 3 : After that run **npm install -g create-react-app@latest**
Step 4 : Next run **npx create-react-app my-react-app**
Step 5 : Happy Hacking